# Using a jquery tooltip more than once on the same page

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

I am using a jquery tooltip on an asp.net repeater element.

```
<div class="tooltip" style="display: none">
<div style="text-align: center; font-weight: bold;">
<%# Eval("Name") %><br />
</div>
</div>


$(function () {
    var du = 1000;
    var tooltip;
    $(document).tooltip({
        show:{effect:'slideDown'},
            items: "h5",
            content: function () {
                tooltip = $(this).siblings('.tooltip');
                return tooltip.html();
        }
    });
    });
```

I now have to implement a help functionality. There should be a help icon and on clicking on the 
        icon a popup should open up with instructions , I would like to use the jquery tooltip again. 
        I do not know how to implement it this time ,should I include it in the same $function() above or 
should I use another function ?

If anyone has any idea please let me know..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you've written it, you shouldn't have to do any more JavaScript. Any `<h5>` element that has a sibling with the `tooltip` class will be activated. All you have to do is put a `.tooltip` div next to the thing that's supposed to activate it. Example:

```html
<ul>
 <li>
   <h5>Here is thing 1.</h5>
   <div class="tooltip" style="display: none">This is tooltip 1.</div>
 </li>
 <li>
   <h5>Here is thing 2.</h5>
   <div class="tooltip" style="display: none">This is tooltip 2.</div>
 </li>
</ul>
```

If you want tooltips to work for elements other than `h5`, modify the `items` option:

```
items: "h5, img.help-icon",
```

Make sure each trigger/tooltip pair are siblings, and make sure you have some type of wrapper around each pair to show which tooltip goes with which element. For example, this will **NOT** work properly:

```html
<li>
  <div>
    <h5>Here is thing 1.</h5>
  </div>
  <div class="tooltip" style="display: none">This won't show up at all!</div>
</li>
```

Neither will this:

```html
<li>
  <h5>Here is thing 1.</h5>
  <div class="tooltip" style="display: none">This will be the text for both tooltips!</div>

  <h5>Here is thing 2.</h5>
  <div class="tooltip" style="display: none">This won't show up at all!</div>
</li>
```